# Problem with exporting static image from Plotly in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: plotly

I'm having serious difficulty exporting my static image (plotly gauge chart) to any format ('jpg', 'png' etc) in Jupyter notebook. I have created the chart and now want include this image in a pdf report. However, in order to do so, the image must be saved as a 'jpg'. When I try to use the pio.write_image() function nothing happens and nothing is saved to my working directory. Here is the code...any help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent days trying to figure this out

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.io as pio
py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

#Cleanining and Filtering Data
con_dec_weekly = 1000
con_dec_sum = 100
    
con_average_week = 850
con_average_dec = 250
    
con_min_dec = 600
con_max_dec = 900

#Creating Figure   
fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
value = con_dec_sum,
mode = "gauge+number+delta",
delta = {'reference': con_average_dec},
gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, 1200]},
            'steps' : [
        {'range': [0, con_min_dec], 'color': "lightgrey"},
        {'range': [con_min_dec, con_max_dec], 'color': "lightgreen"}],
            'threshold' : {'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 4}, 'thickness': 0.75, 'value': con_average_dec}}))
pio.write_image(fig, 'fig1.png')
```

Comment: Works on my end, any errors inside the notebook?

Comment: Thanks Bas. I’m not sure if there may be an issue with one of the package versions as I can’t get the write_image function to work and save to my directory. I’ve managed to use py.offline and get the images into my Downloads folder which I can work with. Thanks again